# laravel preventing duplicate record

Tags: php, laravel

How to properly check if a data already exist in DB and return message into view

```
$check = PropertyReservation::where('res_id', Auth::user()->res_id)->where('property_no',$reservation->property_no)->first();

        if($check){
            return redirect('/reservations')->with('success','You have an existing reservation for this item ' );
        }

        else{
            $reservation->reservation_name = $resident->resident_fname;
            $reservation->reservation_type = $request->input('reservation_type');
            $reservation->reservation_quantity = $request->input('reservation_quantity');
            $reservation->save();
        }

        return redirect('/reservations');
```

Comment: Take a look at [Laravel Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation). You can create a file to check your request and get the response.

Comment: Use just $check = PropertyReservation::where('res_id', Auth::user()->res_id)->where('property_no',$reservation->property_no)->first();

        if(!is_null($check)){
            return redirect('/reservations')->with('success','You have an existing reservation for this item ' );
        }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your check will work as well, as if there is no reservation for your query it returns `null` which means your `else` block will execute. But there is a better method on the query builder called `exists`. So you can try this as well:

```
if(PropertyReservation::where('res_id', Auth::user()->res_id)->where('property_no',$reservation->property_no)->exists();
{
   // redirect back
}

// no need for else block as this will execute if the condition above is false
// save the reservation
```